How to hardcode display refresh rate in AOSP (Android 12)?
Is there a way to hardcode the display refresh rate in AOSP (Android 12)?
I have tried overriding config_defaultRefreshRate and config_defaultPeakRefreshRate, and while the system acknowledged my changes, running adb shell dumpsys display still shows the default refreshRate=60.000004 even when no display is connected to the board.
I also attempted modifying the device tree configuration (DTS), but that didn’t have any effect either. Any suggestions on how to enforce a specific refresh rate?

Are you sure the display refresh rate can be configured simply by changing a value? I thought that this is a special hardware or at least driver feature.
